# Confusion matrix with multi-class multi-label classification

Tags: multi-class, confusion-matrix, multilabel

Let's say I have three possible classes {'isCold' 'isWet' 'isSolid'} and my instances can belong to one or more of these classes.

Ground Truth

- ice = {'isCold' 'isWet' 'isSolid'}
- water = {'isCold' 'isWet'}
- steam = {'isWet'}
- rock = {'isCold' 'isSolid'}

My classifier labels them

- ice = {'isCold' 'isWet' 'isSolid'}
- water = {'isWet'}
- steam = {'isSolid'}
- rock = {'isWet'}

If I wanted to construct a confusion matrix, how do I do it?

The ice case is simple. It's correctly labeled with all it's labels so I add one to all diagonal elements.

For steam, isSolid is being confused with isWet. This also is simple. Add one to (isSolid, isWet) cell.

What do I do for water? isWet is correct, but isCold is missing. Do I just add one to the (isWet, isWet) cell?

Finally for rock isWet is being confused with something, but is it 'isCold' or 'isSolid' or both?